# Spring sessionRegistry gives list of zero logged in users

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

I had taken reference from this article to write a login page
[Krams tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html)

But I changed the sessionRegistry configuration according to latest document

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions

And I get list of principals as 0.

Here is my config file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
            infrastructure -->

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.session" />

    <security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" >



        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/auth/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/common"    access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/users" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <security:logout 
                invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/krams/auth/login" 
            logout-url="/krams/auth/logout" />


        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
                <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <security:session-management    session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

    </security:http>



    <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
            ref="sas" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
            ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/krams/auth/login?error=true"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/krams/main/common"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>





    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"  class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/krams/auth/session-expired" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/krams/auth/login"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService">
            <!-- <security:password-encoder hash="sha" /> -->
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:user-service id="myUserDetailService">
        <security:user name="john" password="admin1234"
            authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:user name="jane" password="admin1234"
            authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>

<!--    <beans:bean id="sas"    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded"
                        value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean> -->

    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
            <beans:property name = "maximumSessions" value="-1" />
            <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
</beans:beans>
```

And here is how I use it in controller

```
     @Autowired
 @Qualifier("sessionRegistry")
 private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;



    /**
  * Handles and retrieves list of logged-in users as JSP view
  * 
  * @return the name of the JSP page
  */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUsersPage(Model model) {
     logger.debug("Received request to show users page");

     logger.debug("Total logged-in users: " + sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size());
     System.out.println("Total logged-in users: " + sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size());
     logger.debug("List of logged-in users: ");
      System.out.println("List of logged-in users: ");

     for (Object username: sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
      logger.debug((String) username);
      System.out.println("names " + (String) username);
     }
     if(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size() == 0)
         return "userspage";
     logger.debug("Total sessions including expired ones: " + sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().get(0), true).size());
     logger.debug("Total sessions: " + sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().get(0), false).size());

     // Attach to model list of users and granted authorities
     model.addAttribute("users", sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals());
     model.addAttribute("total", sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size());

     // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/userspage.jsp
     return "userspage";
 }
```

Here is web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/krams/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can anyone please tell me how is where I am making a mistake?
Is there any configuration missing or wrong?

Comment: Can you update your first link?  Seems to be broken.

Comment: @bphilipnyc Hi corrected the link problem

Comment: You are loading the same configuration twice, duplicating your beans. The bean used in your controller is a different instance then the one used by Spring Security. Split your configuration and don't load everything twice.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you mean sessionRegistry bean ? How do I load it then? I tried using Resource("sessionRegistry") SessionRegistryImpl impl; as well but that didnt work too. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: What is not clear about the fact that all your configuration is loaded twice? Both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` load the same configuration, meaning you are duplicating everything. You are basically loading your whole application twice. You need to separate the core parts (security, services, repositories, datasources etc.) and the web related parts (view resolvers, controllers, etc. etc.) and have them loaded by respectively the `ContextLoaderListener` and the `DispatcherServlet`. This will only load things once and you will get the correct instance.

Comment: Also I would say the configuration (or the tutorial?) is flawed why on earth configure all the beans where you can use the namespace instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` are loading the same configuration. This results in loading your whole application twice, which in turn leads to your Spring Security using a different `SessionRegistry` instance then your controller, the latter is always going to be empty.

You should split your configuration in one that is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and one that is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

The `ContextLoaderListener` one should contain all global things like services, repository, infrastructure beans (DataSources, connection factories etc.) and your security configuration. Also I would say that the configuration you currently have is quite excessive and the same can be achieved by simply using the `security` namespace. Taking that into account the configuration should look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.session">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <security:http use-expressions="true">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/users" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        <security:form-login login-page="/krams/auth/login"
                             default-target-url="/krams/main/common"
                             authentication-failure-url="/krams/auth/login?error=true"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/krams/auth/login"
                         logout-url="/krams/auth/logout"/>

        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" expired-url="/krams/auth/session-expired"/>
        </security:session-management>

    </security:http>



    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="john" password="admin1234" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                <security:user name="jane" password="admin1234" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Your configuration for the `DispatcherServlet` should only load web related beans like controllers, view resolvers, etc. Should look like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

       <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
           infrastructure -->

       <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
       <mvc:annotation-driven />

       <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving
           up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
       <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

       <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
           in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
       </bean>

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.session" use-default-filters="false">
           <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
       </context:component-scan>


</beans>
```

This will result in your beans being loaded once and your controller should get the correct `SessionRegistry` instance.

Comment: how do I do this with spring-boot and annotations?